# Renaming rasters in directory based on field value of centroid feature class in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, modelbuilder

I have a lot of rasters named like r001.tif, r002.tif and so on.

There is a point shapefile with centroids of these rasters and their real name in the attribute table.

I'm looking for a way or some tool/model to rename these rasters according to their real name in centroid point feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial [here](http://johnspeargas.com/geography/gis/python-script-to-rename-files-based-on-a-shapefile-attribute-example-application) that will walk you through the process step by step.  If you do not use Python, you may be able to translate the tutorial's workflow to a model in ArcMap.

```
# Author: John Speargas
# Import module
import os

# Input folder containing files to be renamed
folder = “C:\\GIS\\TEST\\directory_to_be_renamed\\”

# Input lookup table
lookupTable = open(folder + “LookupTable.txt”)

# Read lookup table and close file
tableList = lookupTable.readlines()
lookupTable.close()

# Input fields corresponding to the old and new names
old = “OLD”
new = “NEW”

# Read the lines in the table and strip away unnecessary characters
newTable = []
for line in tableList:
    newLine = line.strip()   
    newerLine = newLine.strip(“,”)  
    newestLine = newerLine.strip(“‘”)   
    almostFinalLine = newestLine.replace(‘”‘,”")  
    finalLine = almostFinalLine.split(“,”)
    newTable.append(finalLine)

# Get position of old and new field names
header = newTable[0]
indexOld = header.index(old) – 1
indexNew = header.index(new) – 1

# Make lists corresponding the new and old values
oldList = []
newList = []
for item in newTable:
    if item != newTable[0]:
        valueOld = item[indexOld]
        valueNew = item[indexNew]
        oldList.append(valueOld)
        newList.append(valueNew)

# For each file in the folder, parse the old name from (the path
# and-?) the extension
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    nameAndExt = os.path.splitext(file)
    oldName = nameAndExt[0]
    extension = nameAndExt[1]

#   Index the old name in the old list if it is present
    if oldName in oldList:
        indexOldName = oldList.index(oldName)

#       Locate the same index in the “new” list
        newName = newList[indexOldName]

#       Rename the file using the path, the new name, and the extension
        os.rename(folder + oldName + extension, folder + newName + extension)
```

Comment: I don`t have lookup table with current raster names.  I need to build it from intersection of rasters with point centroids.